# System.NullReferenceException with windows service of DB connection string

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

I am writting a windows service, and I catch an exception using try:

```
try
{
    connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connStr"].ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    logger.Error("get the connection string failed，detail：" + ex.ToString());
}
```

The output is:

> get the connection string failed，detail：System.NullReferenceException: not set an instance with a object reference.

It can't get the connection string correctly.

And this is my configuration file(app.config) :

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
        <add key="connStr" value="Data Source=Dolphin-PC;Initial Catalog=jsptpd_SYS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=ccir"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Where is wrong?  Why can't get the connection string?

I've been searching from google and can't find where is wrong?

Some reason can cause the problem?

The stack track:

```
 2013-12-13 21:37:19,895 [17] ERROR ApplicationInfoLog [(null)] <(null)>
   - get connection string failed，detail：
     System.NullReferenceException:  not set an instance with a object reference.
     on Jsptpd.JobScheduler.jsptpdJobScheduler.OnStart(String[] args) location     

 D:\jsptpd\Code\jsptpdJobScheduler\jsptpdJobScheduler\jsptpdJobShedule.cs:line 41
```

Comment: What is your meaning?

Comment: The stack trace of the exception, it shows where the exception happens. If .NET framework symbols are there, you'll get a more useful stack trace.

Comment: You should probably be using the ConnectionStrings property of your ConfigurationManager instead. And, of course, use the configuration file correctly.

Comment: Go into executable path and check if you have there YourProgrammName.exe.config with proper content, to make sure your config is in place and valid.

Comment: Not have this file,what should i do?

Comment: Could you declare connStr as string? May be wrong type or it has been already declared as static?

Comment: This is my declare statement:string connStr = "";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your program location don't have a **programName.exe.config** file,the ConfigurationManager can't access the content,so make sure the file exist.

Or you can link there to know more about ConfigurationManager :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: I thought that originally but notice he's actually got the string stored in the AppSettings section of the config file

Answer (score 1):

You're looking in the wrong part of the ConfigurationManager.

Try putting the ConnectionString in the ConnectionStrings area of the web.config and calling

```
connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"];
```

If you're still having issues put a breakpoint on the line and see which ConnectionStrings are being loaded.