# How to read connection string from config file

Tags: c#, windows-services, app-config

ex1:

```
var myCon = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Emp;User ID=sa;Password=sa";
```

ex2:

```
var myCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConString"].ConnectionString;
```

I'm trying to read connection string from app.config file in my windows service application like above (ex2).

It is throwing null reference error with ex2 where as if I hard code my connection string like ex1, it is working fine.

How can I read my connection string from my config file?

Note: I can able to read the same con string from Winforms application. Whereas the same code is not working in Windows Service application.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568001/system-nullreferenceexception-with-windows-service-of-db-connection-string.

Comment: Can you show the config file?.Can you iterate on ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ?Is your file copied to output?From where to you call this code?

Comment: Excellent... After I copied my config file to destination folder it is working perfectly. Thank you :)